# String to Time, but without the limitations of strtotime()

Tags: date, strtotime

In my (non-public) applications, I like for my users to be able to enter the date/time in whatever format and then use strtotime() along with date() to translate it to YYYY-MM-DD for DB storage.  I know this has a couple of drawbacks (such as how 1/1/13 vs. 1-1-13 might be handled based on locale and such), but over the years these have never been an issue given my user base.

However, there is one issue that I may have to resolve, and that's with handling dates prior to 1970 in one particular application.  For obvious reasons, strtotime() doesn't work so well.  I know I could use a date-picker, but was wonder if there is a more proper way of handling this that would allow me to do what I've been doing but to handle a wider range of dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this, I did some additional testing, and it seems on the system I'm working on right now (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit), there are no issues with early.. perhaps this is a 64-bit thing?

```
print date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "May 5, 1820" ));
```

Prints `1820-05-05` as I wanted but not as I expected.  I'm not sure if this is related to the version of Linux I'm running, the version of PHP I'm running, or what else.  But since it hasn't worked this way for me in the past, I don't necessarily feel comfortable dealing with dates like this.

I did find the DateTime object, so I think I'm going to use that approach, especially since it is supposed to handle a much wider range of dates:

```
$date = new DateTime( "May 5, 1820" );
print $oop->format( "Y-m-d" );
```

I'll leave my answer unaccepted for a bit in case someone else has a better or more correct solution to this.

Comment: If this `strtotime("May 5, 1820")` is working, that means that timestamp is returning negative. I have 64bit machine, but it returns `false`, so don't bet on this function. **Like you already found out, DateTime is the way to go.** DateTime is a very powerfull tool for all date/time calculations/modifications.